# What type of new project for the Hibernate tutorial?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to follow this Hibernate tutorial:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

which seems pretty easy & straightforward, but I got stuck on the very 1st decision point: When selecting `File` > `New Project` to use the tutorial's suggested [pom.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-setup), **which** of the many type of projects should I select?

Intuitively, I thought of creating a new Maven project:

1. `Maven` > `Maven Project` [Next]
2. `[v] Create a simple project (skip archtype selection)` [Next]

But at step #3 it prompts me for the very same information provided by the tutorial's [pom.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-setup). So I am thinking the tutorial was aiming at creating a "blank project" and then manually adding the suggested pom.xml to it?

But what type of "blank project" would that be?

- Java?
- Java EE?
- EJB?
- JAXB?
- JPA?
- Maven?
- Does it matter?

(sorry, don't have much experience (yet) with this new jargon, will get there eventually)

**UPDATE 1:** Actually, the proposed method of selecting a **Maven** project (regardless whether starting with bogus or correct info) doesn't work:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial
POM Location: C:\Users\Daniel\Workspace\First Hibernate Tutorial\pom.xml
Validation Messages:

    [0]  'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar
    [1]  'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar
    [2]  'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar
    [3]  'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for javassist:javassist:jar


Reason: Failed to validate POM for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial at C:\Users\Daniel\Workspace\First Hibernate Tutorial\pom.xml
```

I am going to check now whether creating a plain Java project, then **converting** it to a Maven (*after* copying that tutorial's pom.xml) will do the trick.

**UPDATE 2:** Creating a plain Java project, then **converting** it to a Maven (*after* copying that tutorial's pom.xml) produces the same errors.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 3:** Thanks to @cowls tip below I found that "I" was missing were the version numbers for the Maven dependencies. "I" because it's the tutorial that was missing them (what kind of a tutorial is this?)

Once I used some known version numbers, e.g.:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
     </dependency>

    <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on the servlet api. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have been able to get rid of that scary FATAL ERROR message. That error message's "tip" BTW was counter-productive as it was pointing to the wrong direction:

```
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
```

Now... I am still getting a build error, albeit much less scary:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building First Hibernate Tutorial
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\dben\ws-study\First Hibernate Tutorial\src\main\resources
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/1.2_02/servlet-api-1.2_02.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:pom:1.2_02' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/1.2_02/servlet-api-1.2_02.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:1.2_02' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:1.2_02

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=1.2_02 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=1.2_02 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:1.2_02

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Interesting tutorial: I was expecting to learn some Hibernate but instead I am finding myself learning Maven. :)

**UPDATE 4:**  I corrected the `javax.servlet` version to **2.4** and all is well now.

**LESSONS LEARNED:**

1. Maven's pom.xml requires a `<version>` for each & every dependency.
2. That `<version>`'s value must be valid.
3. Creating a new Maven project, then replacing its pom.xml entirely would work, but it still creates it with the incorrect subdirectory under Workspace because there is no way to define the `<name>` in the wizard-based creation process.
4. Creating a plain `Java Project`, then adding the `pom.xml` to its directory, then refreshing the Package Explorer view is the recommended way to go (no subdirectory renaming necessary).
5. That tutorial recommends Maven's "standard layout" but then breaks it by using the declared package "org.hibernate.tutorial.domain" which does not match the expected package "main.java.org.hibernate.tutorial.domain"... **Do** take Eclipse's fix suggestion to rename the package to *"main.java.org.hibernate.tutorial.domain"*. (and move Event.java to the newly renamed package!)
6. The [Hibernate configuration command](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration) (`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hsqldb.Server"` etc.) must be run from the directory where pom.xml resides.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml, im guessing you are missing version numbers in the dependencies Ive updated my answer re: dependency versions, check you have these set.

Comment: @cowls My pom.xml is **exactly** this one: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-setup

Comment: I am not sure why that tutorial doesnt have version numbers. as they are required in a maven dependency. Hence the errors you are seeing. Try adding them using the method in my answer it should fix your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to create a new maven project and use the `maven-archetype-quickstart` archetype.

This will create a basic maven project and you should be able to go from there.

Note that a maven project is just a Java project that uses Maven to build it, hence you will see a pom.xml file in your project.

Using this pom file you can build the project, include external dependencies and much more. I would suggest using the m2e plugin if you are developing with eclipse to help you manage the maven projects better: http://eclipse.org/m2e/

Each dependency you specify should have a version number associated with it.

e.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

To get the correct version number, just google artifactid maven dependency. E.g. hibernate-core maven dependency.

Look for the link for the maven central repository - i.e. http://mvnrepository.com. If you cant find it on Google you can search directly on the site, however I find its search feature quite poor.

Put your Java code in `src/main/java` and your resources in `src/main/resources` (e.g. xml files etc).

You can then build the project using `mvn clean install`

Comment: Great. Thanks! That's what I did but then it prompts me to enter all those `pom.xml` details such as `Group Id`, `Artifact Id`, `Version`, etc. -- which are included in the tutorial's `pom.xml`. Should I just enter bogus info and then immediately replace that `pom.xml` with the tutorial's?

Comment: You could do that, or just put the correct info in at the prompt and then add the dependencies etc later

Comment: As for the m2eclipse plugin, it has been superseded by [m2e](http://blog.frankel.ch/migrating-from-m2eclipse-to-m2e) -- which I already installed. :)

Comment: Ok great, I forget which is the latest :) Updated answer

Comment: OK. I just tried the "bogus info approach" and it seems that it is better to start with the correct info at the prompt, since the `<name>` tag is used to name the Eclipse project's subdirectory itself. Hopefully this tip will enter that wonderful tutorial at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the version tip. I re-accepted your answer and see my update. The tutorial says: *"This tutorial expects the user have knowledge of both **Java** and **SQL**."*. It says nothing about being a **Maven** expert. :)

Comment: Ok, strange that theyve missed that. Youre new error might be fixed by using version 2.5 for servlet-api. (Updated my answer)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in my **UPDATE 4**. :) Thanks a million!